# Minecraft Stronghold

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

I have never played Minecraft for anything but fun and creating things in survival but, now, I am looking to find the stronghold and defeat the Ender Dragon. I have made multiple Eye of Enders but each time I throw them on my Xbox 360 they burst into nothing after going so far. I have dug all the way down to bedrock and found nothing each time it happens. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Related (but does not cover how to properly use Eyes of Ender): [How can I find my World's Strongholds?](//gaming.stackexchange.com/q/30340)

Answer (score 4):

Eyes of ender will fly in the direction of the stronghold, but not all the way there.

For example, if you throw an eye and it heads north-east before bursting or dropping out of the air (random chance), then you should head north-east.

You should throw new ones occasionally while heading in this direction, and you will know when you have passed the stronghold when eyes start flying back in the other direction.

When you're directly above the stronghold, the eyes will fly down into the ground rather than upwards; this is when you should start digging down.

Comment: My map has a lot of water and the Eyes of Ender travel towards a large area of water. What is the best way to travel across the water? Also, how can I find the Stronghold when the Eyes of Ender are vanishing after only one throw?

Comment: @UBxM4C Best thing is to use MATH and triangulation. Open F3 and write down coordinates and angle the eye were flying at from you. Repeat from another place, then you have two points, one side and two angles - you can easily count the rest of triangle and get exact coordinates plus minus some tens of blocks, depending on accuracy of your measurement (you need to be accurate to look exactly at the eye after you thrown it straight up). Also you know that this is like 700-1200 blocks away from original spawn. This method is accurate and you need only like two eyes. Enjoy!

Comment: @UBxM4C just be aware to not mix two strongholds into one measurement, that would lead you into nothingness and not a stronghold. Also if you are too away from spawnpoint, you will find nothing, even they will point at some points (fake stronghold spots when you are too away from spawn) - but only in old versions, new versions have added more strongholds than 3.

Comment: @UBxM4C Boats are generally the best way to travel across water. If they're vanishing after one throw, bring a lot of them.

Answer (score 1):

This has happened to me before on my ps4.
The problem should be that you have had an update in that world before you looked for the stronghold. If so the problem is that you are playing on the old version of the world’s seed. When an update came along the new world for that seed has a new location of coordinates for the stronghold.
Your best bet for finding the stronghold is making a new world with the same seed and locate the stronghold in creative, then Write down the coordinates and travel to them in the other world the stronghold should be there.

Answer (score -3):

Keep throwing the eyes of ender until you are led somewhere special. The coordinates are usually something fancy.